# How can I gain access to my Gmail account with my password but without a recovery phone number or email?

Tags: google-account, account-recovery

I know my Gmail username and password. I don't have any recovery phone number or email. I recently moved to another location within the United States and Gmail won't let me access my account:

[image]

I tried:

[image]

where they ask when I created my account and an email address where to send a  verification code, but it didn't work.

[image]

How can I gain access to my Gmail account with my password but without a recovery phone number or email?

Comment: When locked out of my google account, I had to contact google, explain my situation, and they sent me a form to fill out. After filling out that form I had to wait 3 full business days before being let into my account

Comment: @ZachSaucier how did you contact Google?

Comment: I can't remember exactly. It was after I had attempted to verify my account via answering questions